# Как воспользоваться getApplicationContext() в отдельном классе?

Tags: java, android

Создал класс Eph вне Activity, но как получить Context, чтобы работал метод getApplicationContext() в следующем коде?

```
public class Eph {
int x1,x2;

void cChart {
    new CopyAssetfiles(".*\\.st1", getApplicationContext()).copy();
    SwE sw = new SwE(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + File.separator + "/epit");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** Передать в конструктор `Context`

```
public class Eph {
    private Context context;

    int x1,x2;

    public Eph(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    void cChart() {
        new CopyAssetfiles(".*\\.st1", getApplicationContext()).copy();
        SwE sw = new SwE(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "/epit");
    }
}
```

**2)** Унаследоваться от Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

затем добавить в манифесте в тэг `<application>`

```
android:name="your.package.MyApplication"
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все заработало!